# How to cast field to specific class using reflection in java?

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to put all my class's member variables that are of type `Card` class into an `ArrayList<Card>` instance. How do I finish this last part (see commented line below)?

```
ArrayList<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field : fields) {
   if (field.getType() == Card.class) {
      //how do I convert 'field' to a 'Card' object and add it to the 'cardList' here?
```

Comment: Why do you need reflection to access the fields on `this`?

Comment: I want to get every field that is of type 'Card'

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Field` is just the description of the field, it is not the value contained in there.

You need to first get the value, and then you can cast it:

```
Card x =  (Card) field.get(this);
```

Also, you probably want to allow subclasses as well, so you should do

```
  //  if (field.getType() == Card.class) {

  if (Card.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) {
```

Comment: "this" does not work in static method, any workaround to do it in static methods? @Thilo

Comment: For a static field, you can pass in `null` to `field.get(null)`. If you have another instance, you can pass it in as well, it does not have to be `this`: `field.get(anInstance)`.

Comment: what does the parameter(this,null,anInstance, whatever) do here?

Comment: @WVrock It specifies the instance of which the field should be accessed. For static fields, it is not necessary and can be `null`.

Answer (score 6):

```
ArrayList<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();    

for (Field field : fields) {
   if (field.getType() == Card.class) {
      Card tmp = (Card) field.get(this);
      cardList.add(tmp);
```

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi where you able to find a solution to your question?